pytest Database access not allowed
I am trying to run my tests with access to an existing database to reuse it.
Here is the error:
ERROR drf/tests/test_auth.py - RuntimeError: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.

here is the pytest.ini
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = drf.tests.test_settings
python_files = test_*.py
django_debug_mode = true
pythonpath = .venv/bin/python
addopts = --reuse-db --create-db

here is the test_settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR + '/tests', 'dump_test.sql'),
    }
}

Here is a simplified version of the test:
@pytest.mark.django_db
class AuthTestCase:
    def test_two_step_authentication(self):
        user = UsersFactory.create()

        # Initialize the API client
        client = APIClient()

        # Step 1: Authenticate the user to get the initial token
        url_step1 = reverse('token-auth-s1')
        credentials = {
            'email': user.email,
            'password': 'password123'
        }
        response_step1 = client.post(url_step1, credentials, format='json')

        # Assert the response status code
        assert response_step1.status_code == 200

The directory structure:
drf
├── drf
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── dump_test.sql
│   │   ├── factory_boy
│   │   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   │   ├── factory_models.py
│   │   │   └── languages_factory.py
│   │   ├── test_auth.py
│   │   └── test_settings.py
├── manage.py
└── pytest.ini

List of things I have tried so far:

Using @pytest.mark.django_db and @pytest.mark.django_db(True) but got the same error.
Moving @pytest.mark.django_db before the function, but got the same error.
Originally, the database was PostgreSQL in Docker, but for simplicity, I dumped the content into test_dump.sql.
Split the settings.py into test_settings.py and set the SQLite database.
Checked with os.path.exists for the path of dump_test.sql, which returns True.

If anyone has idea I take it, thank you!
